# Live Agent "Visitor" show while chatting

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat-api

I have configured live agent on the community, hence whenever the chat gets initiated, it shows "Visitor" instead of the Customer Community user Contact, Can you please let me know is there a way to captures the Customer Community Contact in the Chat session.